# how to add multiple markers angular google maps?

Tags: angular, google-maps

i used @agm/core module from npm install @agm/core

this is my code

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" >
<agm-marker *ngFor="let data of rooms"[latitude]="data.lat_long[0].lat" [longitude]="data.lat_long[0].long"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

and this component.ts

```
export class ResultComponent implements OnInit {
  lat: number ;
  lng: number ;
  rooms = ROOMS;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rooms = ROOMS;
    this.lat =  -6.914744;
    this.lng = 107.609810;

  }

}
```

but that's only showing one markers how to add multiple markers using `*ngFor` ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have lat and long defined in each item of your array

```
 <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="long">
   <agm-marker  *ngFor="let data of rooms; let i = index" [latitude]="data.lat" [longitude]="data.long">
   </agm-marker>
 </agm-map>
```

Comment: Why agm-marker in a loop inside agm-marker? was that by purpose or did you mean agm-map in the parent element?

Answer (score 4):

chances are that all your markers are shown on the map correctly; but the map is centered on just one of them; try to zoom out and see for yourself.

starting **rxjs@6**, there is a way to center/zoom your map on the markers automatically [AgmFitBounds](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/agmfitbounds):

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [fitBounds]="true">
  <agm-marker *ngFor="let data of rooms"
    [latitude]="data.lat_long[0].lat [longitude]="data.lat_long[0].long"
    [agmFitBounds]="true">
  </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Comment: The best answer and the only one that works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you referencing `data.lat_long[0]` for your lat and long? It makes me wonder if you really want this:

```
<agm-marker  *ngFor="let data of rooms.lat_long" [latitude]="data.lat" [longitude]="data.long">
```

or this

```
<agm-marker  *ngFor="let data of rooms" [latitude]="data.lat_long.lat" [longitude]="data.lat_long.long">
```

It all depends on how your ROOMS model is set up

Comment: this is my dummy data structure
` {
        id_room : 1,
        name_room : 'Name1',
        rating_room : 3,
        price_room : 200000,
        lat_long : [{lat : -7.025253, long:107.519760}],
        latitude : 1122331123 ,
        longitude : 123123123123,
        city :  'City 1',
        country : 'Country 1'
    }`

Comment: hmm... well everything you have looks right, so the only other thing I can think of is to confirm you have multiple elements in your `this.room`. Because you should have something like this `[{ id_room : 2, name_room : 'Name2', price_room : 200000, lat_long : [{lat : -7.025253, long:107.519760}]}, { id_room : 2, name_room : 'Name2', price_room : 2000, lat_long : [{lat : -10, long:100}]}]` where your lat_long are in fact different points.

Answer (score 0):

component.html

```
<agm-map [latitude]='lat' [longitude]='lng'>
    <agm-marker *ngFor='let loc of mylocations' [latitude]='loc.lat' [longitude]='loc.lng'></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

component.ts

```
private mylocations = [
    { lat: 7.423568, lng: 80.462287 },
    { lat: 7.532321, lng: 81.021187 },
    { lat: 6.117010, lng: 80.126269 }
];
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.